# Interpretación de cadenas recibidas por el puerto serie

Tags: c

Estoy implementando una UART en un microcontrolador, pero tengo problemas en la interpretación de los caracteres que forman la cadena.

El código es el siguiente:

```
typedef struct
{
    DEBUG_PORT_STATES       state;
    APP_STATUS_t            Status;

    USART_OBJECT            *pObject;
    uint8_t                 rx_buffer;
    uint8_t                 tx_buffer;

} DEBUG_PORT_DATA;

DEBUG_PORT_DATA debugportData;

#define     DEBUG_PORT_BUFFER_SIZE  128
// Opciones del menú del puerto de mantenimiento
#define     MAIN_MENU           0x30      // 0 + '48' -> Caracter 0 en ASCII = 48 = 0x30
#define     OPTION_2          0x31      // 1 + '48' -> Caracter 1 en ASCII = 49 = 0x31

{
    static uint8_t select_command = MAIN_MENU;
    static uint8_t num_char = 0;
    uint8_t rx_buffer[DEBUG_PORT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    if(USART_BytesAvailable(debugportData.pObject))
    {
        USART_ReceiveString ( debugportData.pObject, (uint8_t *)(&(debugportData.rx_buffer)), 1, false );
        select_command = debugportData.rx_buffer;
    
        if (select_command != '\r') // Almacena la cadena en un "rx_buffer" hasta que se envíe un retorno de carro (ENTER))
        {
            rx_buffer[num_char] = select_command;
            printf("%c", rx_buffer[num_char]);
            num_char++;
            break;
        }

        switch (rx_buffer[num_char])    // He probado rx_buffer[num_char-1] y tampoco funciona
        { 
            num_char = 0;
            case MAIN_MENU:
            {
                printf("MENU PRINCIPAL");
                break;
            }
            case OPTION_2:
            {
                printf("OPCION 2");
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                printf("Comando incorreto\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }               
}
```

El modo de funcionamiento es:

1. Cada vez que introduzca por puerto serie un carácter se almacena en `rx_buffer`
2. Cuando detecte el retorno de carro `\r` (tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) que empiece a valorar la cadena.
3. Primero estoy intentando comparar únicamente el último carácter introducido: `rx_buffer[num_char]`. También he probado `rx_buffer[num_char-1]` y `rx_buffer[num_char-2]`.

En las líneas de código:

```
if (select_command != '\r') // Almacena la cadena en un "rx_buffer" hasta que se envíe un retorno de carro (ENTER))
{
   rx_buffer[num_char] = select_command;
   printf("%c", rx_buffer[num_char]);
   num_char++;
   break;
}
```

Imprimo por puerto serie los caracteres que voy introduciendo, y los visualizo perfectamente. Es decir, si introduzco la `h`, la `o` y la `t`, veo por el terminal `hot`, pero a la hora de valorar el carácter en el `switch` siempre se me va al estado de `default`, visualizando el mensaje `"Comando incorrecto"`.

Supongo que es un tema de interpretación de valores enteros de los caracteres, o que `rx_buffer` contiene basura, o que cada vez que entro en la función no se me queda guardada la información.

¿Alguna idea al respecto?

PD: Este error lo tengo cuando trabajo con una matriz, ya que cuando trabajaba en el `switch` con un `uint8_t` funcionaba correctamente, por lo que la implementación de la UART es correcta.

Comment: Para empezar, sería `rx_buffer[num_char - 1]` porque en el carácter anterior incrementaste `num_char`. Por otro lado, ¿estás pulsando los caracteres `0` o `1` antes del retorno del carro? ¿Has probado a depurar ese carácter con un `printf("Comprobando: %c\n", rx_buffer[num_char - 1]);`? Además, creo que `uint8_t rx_buffer` debería ser también estático para que se mantenga su contenido entre llamadas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia solucionado! Era la volatilidad del array. Al no ser estático no me estaba guardando los valores entre iteraciones, y como quedaba a la espera del retorno de carro siempre iba a tener mínimo 2 caracteres en el array, por lo que cuando entraba por segunda vez, y cogía el penúltimo carácter, éste contenía basura. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Otro comentario... ¿Cómo puedo hacer ahora para comparar la cadena entera? Es decir, actualmente únicamente comparo el último carácter introducido, pero si quiero comparar en el `switch` si he introducido una cadena en particular?

Comment: No puedes usar un `switch` para comparar cadenas de caracteres. Debes usar para ello [`strcmp()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) con bloques `if`/`else`.

Comment: Lo que me temía... Vale, muchas gracias @OscarGarcia por la aclaración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, habría que usar `rx_buffer[num_char - 1]` porque en el carácter anterior incrementaste `num_char`:

```
switch (rx_buffer[num_char - 1]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Por otro lado, `uint8_t rx_buffer` debería ser también estático para que se mantenga su contenido entre llamadas:

```
static uint8_t rx_buffer[DEBUG_PORT_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Para continuar, si quieres comprobar cadenas de caracteres tendrás que hacer lo siguiente:

- Agregar un carácter nulo al final de la cadena.
- Volver a colocar el índice del carácter de la cadena al comienzo de ella.
- Usar [`strcmp()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) para comprobar el contenido de la cadena.

Y, para terminar, debes evitar un agujero de seguridad muy común, que es el [desbordamiento de la matriz o del búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) (*buffer overflow* o *buffer overrun* en inglés).

Estas dos últimas cosas podrían implementarse de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Comprobamos que no haya llegado un retorno del carro y que
    no hayamos superado el tamaño de la cadena de caracteres */
if (
    select_command != '\r'
    && num_char < DEBUG_PORT_BUFFER_SIZE
) {
    rx_buffer[num_char] = select_command;
    printf("%c", rx_buffer[num_char]);
    num_char++;
    break;
}
/* Finalizamos la cadena */
rx_buffer[num_char] = 0;
/* Volvemos al inicio de la cadena */
num_char = 0;
/* Ahora podemos usar "strcmp()" sin problemas */
if (strcmp("hola", rx_buffer) == 0) {
    /* Hacer algo al pulsar "hola" */
} else if (strcmp("saludos", rx_buffer) == 0) {
    /* Hacer algo al pulsar "saludos" */
} else if (strcmp("adios", rx_buffer) == 0) {
    /* Hacer algo al pulsar "adios" */
} else {
    /* Hacer algo en caso contrario */
}
```